# How to autofill Excel cells by week?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I type in 7/1/2011 into cell A1.  I autofill/drag down the grippie and the cells beneath fill with an incremental days.

Is there a way to autofill by week?  In other words, cell A2 should be 7/8/2011, cell A3 should be 7/15/2011 and so on.

Edit: fixed omission mentioned by @jonsca

Comment: When you say A1, B1, C1, do you mean A1, A2, A3, etc.?  As you said dragging down, but A1, B1, C1 implies across.

Comment: @johsca You are correct.  I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you just want to drag down, put 07/01/2011 in A1, and 07/08/2011 in A2, select them both and drag the grippie down.

Comment: That "grippie" would be the "cell handle" then? ;-) +1 for a straight forward answer.

Comment: @Adam I was going with the parlance :)

Answer (score 8):

I post this as an alternative solution to jonsca's solution.  In Cell A1, you can put your starting date.  Then, in cell A2, put the formula `=A1+7`.  Then, just click and drag down cell A2 as far as you need.  If you want to change the starting date, just change the date in cell A1.

Again, the other way to do this would be as jonsca mentioned, by using Excel's "smart" auto fill feature.  It detects the difference between two cells and auto-increments it using the drag-to-fill-down feature.  The only advantage to the method I posted would be if you need to change the starting date.

Comment: I changed mine a little because the OP seems to want the weeks across the top, and days down, but I'm not absolutely sure of this.

Comment: @jonsca If this is what the original author wants, then he can just change `A2` to `B1` and drag/auto-fill to the right instead of down.